# undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf13TransformableD2Ev'

Tags: c++, linker

Ive just installed DEV-C on windows 7 starter and have managed to successfully compile a small c++ program to read an image file and then display it in a window. Im using SFML.

Ive included these references in the project directories:
    SFML-2.3.2\include
    SFML-2.3.2\lib

However, it wont link. Here is the compile log. It is a bit incomprehensible to me as i am still learning how to use it.

COMPILE LOG:
    vbrowse1.o:vbrowse1.cpp:(.text$_ZN2sf6SpriteD1Ev[__ZN2sf6SpriteD1Ev]+0x5e):    undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf13TransformableD2Ev'

### collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

HERE IS THE MAKE FILE:

```
    # Project: vbrowse
    # Makefile created by Dev-C++ 5.11

    CPP      = g++.exe
    CC       = gcc.exe
    WINDRES  = windres.exe
    OBJ      = vbrowse1.o
    LINKOBJ  = vbrowse1.o
    LIBS     = -L"C:/Program Files/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib32" -L"C:/Program Files/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib32" -static-libgcc -L"C:/SFML-2.3.2/lib" -mwindows -m32
    INCS     = -I"C:/Program Files/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Program Files/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/Program Files/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include" -I"C:/SFML-2.3.2/include"
CXXINCS  = -I"C:/Program Files/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/include" -I"C:/Program Files/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include" -I"C:/Program Files/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include" -I"C:/Program Files/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++" -I"C:/SFML-2.3.2/include"
    BIN      = vbrowse.exe
   CXXFLAGS = $(CXXINCS) -m32
   CFLAGS   = $(INCS) -m32
   RM       = rm.exe -f

   .PHONY: all all-before all-after clean clean-custom

   all: all-before $(BIN) all-after

  clean: clean-custom
    ${RM} $(OBJ) $(BIN)

  $(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)

   vbrowse1.o: vbrowse1.cpp
    $(CPP) -c vbrowse1.cpp -o vbrowse1.o $(CXXFLAGS)

   C:\eyeball\vbrowse\Makefile.win:25: recipe for target 'vbrowse.exe' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [vbrowse.exe] Error 1
```

---

Can anyone spot the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Without a look at the source code it's hard to say what `Transformable` is ment. Is this implemented in a library? In that case you missed to add the library to `LIBS`. If it's in a different source file you missed to add the corresponding `.o` file to ÒBJ` and the rule to compile the source file to the Makefile.

Comment: You've added the path to the SFML libraries to the library paths. You also need to add the SFML libraries you're using to the linker inputs. (I have no idea how to this with your IDE.)